# How to match credentails using XML on login HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, validation, xml-parsing

Locally I am trying to match the login credentails using the XML page which will act like database. If the login credentails matches, it must proceed to next page which will be new HTML page containing something. Here's what I have till now in HTML & XML page. I did the validation using the JavaScript and hard coded for one user. In XML if I have say 10 users then how do I do?

```
<html>
<head><title>Login page</title></head>
<body>

<div align="right">
<h1 style="font-family:Times New Roman;text-align="center";font-size:20pt;
color:#00FF00;>
Welcome to Login Page
</h1>
<form name="login">
Username: &nbsp <input type="text" name="userid"/><br><br>
Password:  &nbsp  <input type="password" name="paasword"/><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
{
/*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
if(form.userid.value == "user1" && form.password.value == "pass1")
{
window.open('success.html')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
}
else
{
alert("wrong Username or Password")/*displays error message*/
}
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<student>

<details>
<username>user1</username>
<password>pass1</password>
<email>user1@abc.com</email>
</details>

<details>
<username>user2</username>
<password>pass2</password>
<email>user2@abc.com</email>
</details>

<details>
<username>user3</username>
<password>pass3</password>
<email>user3@abc.com</email>
</details>

<details>
<username>user4</username>
<password>pass4</password>
<email>user4@abc.com</email>
</details>

</student>
```

Comment: Storing user data in XML? Hmmm....

Comment: @JoranDenHouting Yes, into the XML file, while will be like our local database. How to I macth and move to next page, say success.html which page 2 here.. Please help me with this.. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery and do something like this..

```
<html>
<head><title>Login page</title></head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var xml;
  $('#b1').click(function(){
       $.get('users.xml', null, function (data, textStatus) {
           xml=data;
            $(xml).find('details').each( function(){
                var item = $(this);

                if(item.find('username').text()==$('#userid').val() && item.find('password').text()==$('#pwd').val())
                {
                    window.open('success.html');
                }
           });
        });
    });
});
    </script>
<body>
<div align="right">
<h1> Welcome to Login Page </h1>
Username: &nbsp <input type="text" id="userid" name="userid"/><br><br>
Password:  &nbsp  <input type="password" id="pwd" name="paasword"/><br><br>
<input type="button" id="b1" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i have to use xml file data to be read and verify with username and passoword on html Page.plz help

Comment: yeah thats what i did

Comment: Check now, whats output u r getting

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `XML` file for each user, which will have better performance.

Then when login, check if the file exsists and read the password out of it:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
$username = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', $_POST['username']);
$password = $_POST['password'];
if(file_exists('users/' . $username . '.xml')){
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('users/' . $username . '.xml', 0, true);
    if($password == $xml->password){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: index.php');
        die;
    } else {
                echo "wrong password";
            }
} else {
    echo "User not found";
}
?>
```

I would suggest to use some password encryption too, like this:

```
$password = base_64_encode(md5($_POST['password']));
```

Ofcourse you'll need to save the passwordt using the same encoding in your `XML` files.

Comment: PHP isn't the language I am using as I have no knowledge of it. I'm trying only XML and HTML.